# SQL Join, Aggregate with Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to create a custom report from an inventory system. Unfortunately in the system UI, there is only an option to use the query for custom reports. I want to generate the asset report with the asset state e.g. Faulty, New - In-Store, Used.

```
SELECT  productType.COMPONENTTYPENAME AS "Product Type", "state"."displaystate" AS "Asset State", count("resource"."resourcename" ) AS "Asset Count" FROM Resources resource
left JOIN ComponentDefinition product ON resource.COMPONENTID=product.COMPONENTID
left JOIN ComponentType productType ON product.COMPONENTTYPEID=productType.COMPONENTTYPEID
LEFT JOIN "resourcestate" "state" ON "resource"."resourcestateid" = "state"."resourcestateid"
LEFT JOIN "resourcetype" "rtype" ON "productType"."resourcetypeid" = "rtype"."resourcetypeid"
GROUP BY  state.displaystate,productType.COMPONENTTYPENAME
```

with this query, i am getting the data in this format

| Product Type | Asset State | Asset Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Workstation | In Use | 30 |
| Keyb_Mouse | In Use | 30 |
| Workstation | New - In Store | 10 |
| Keyb_Mouse | Used - In Store | 20 |
| Workstation | Used - In Store | 20 |

I want to convert this Asset state in rows into columns like (Excel Pivot Table) to get the summary.

I tried to change the query to change the result to this format.

| Product Type | In Use | New - In Store | Used - In Store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Workstation | 30 | 10 | 20 |
| Keyb_Mouse | 30 | 20 |  |

```
SELECT  productType.COMPONENTTYPENAME AS "Product Type", "state"."displaystate" AS "Asset State", count("resource"."resourcename" ) AS "Asset Count" FROM Resources resource
left JOIN ComponentDefinition product ON resource.COMPONENTID=product.COMPONENTID
left JOIN ComponentType productType ON product.COMPONENTTYPEID=productType.COMPONENTTYPEID
LEFT JOIN "resourcestate" "state" ON "resource"."resourcestateid" = "state"."resourcestateid"
LEFT JOIN "resourcetype" "rtype" ON "productType"."resourcetypeid" = "rtype"."resourcetypeid"
GROUP BY  state.displaystate,productType.COMPONENTTYPENAME

SELECT "Asset State", "In Use", "Used - In Store", "In Store", "New - In Store", "Damaged","Faulty" FROM Resources resource
PIVOT(
sum("Asset Count") for "Asset State" in ("In Use", "Used - In Store", "In Store", "New - In Store", "Damaged", "Faulty")
)
```

but this query is not returning anything. Kindly refer to any link or video to understand and fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without sample data, expected output and table schemas this is not answerable. Side point: you should ideally not use `"` for quoting, use `[]` instead

Answer (score 0):

The below query solved the issue. Suggestions are most welcome to improve the query.

```
SELECT  "Product Type", "In Use", "Used - In Store", "In Store", "New - In Store", "Damaged","Faulty" FROM (
SELECT  productType.COMPONENTTYPENAME AS "Product Type", "state"."displaystate" AS "Asset State", count("resource"."resourcename" ) AS "Asset Count" FROM Resources resource
left JOIN ComponentDefinition product ON resource.COMPONENTID=product.COMPONENTID
left JOIN ComponentType productType ON product.COMPONENTTYPEID=productType.COMPONENTTYPEID
LEFT JOIN "resourcestate" "state" ON "resource"."resourcestateid" = "state"."resourcestateid"
LEFT JOIN "resourcetype" "rtype" ON "productType"."resourcetypeid" = "rtype"."resourcetypeid"
GROUP BY  state.displaystate,productType.COMPONENTTYPENAME )d
pivot
(
  max("Asset Count")
  for "Asset State" in ("In Use", "Used - In Store", "In Store", "New - In Store", "Damaged", "Faulty")
) piv
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to name the first part of the query as a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so it would be like:

```
;with Resources as (
    SELECT productType.COMPONENTTYPENAME AS [Product Type],
    [state].[displaystate] AS [Asset State],
    count([resource].[resourcename] ) AS [Asset Count]
    FROM Resources resource
        left JOIN ComponentDefinition product ON resource.COMPONENTID=product.COMPONENTID
        left JOIN ComponentType productType ON product.COMPONENTTYPEID=productType.COMPONENTTYPEID
        LEFT JOIN [resourcestate] [state] ON [resource].[resourcestateid] = [state].[resourcestateid]
        LEFT JOIN [resourcetype] [rtype] ON [productType].[resourcetypeid] = [rtype].[resourcetypeid]
    GROUP BY  state.displaystate,productType.COMPONENTTYPENAME
)
SELECT [Asset State], [In Use], [Used - In Store], [In Store], [New - In Store], [Damaged], [Faulty]
FROM Resources resource
PIVOT(
    sum([Asset Count]) for [Asset State] in ([In Use], [Used - In Store], [In Store], [New - In Store], [Damaged], [Faulty])
)
```